# SQL. DateDiff between rows under conditions determined by parsing row contents

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a set of data that goes sort of like:

```
TimeStamp    | Action
-------------+-------------------------
'2016-01-01' | 'State changed to 1'
'2016-01-03' | 'State changed to 2'
'2016-01-07' | 'State changed to 1'
'2016-01-12' | 'State changed to 2'
'2016-01-20' | 'State changed to Final'
```

What I need to count is how much time have the object spent in the state '1', how much time it spent in state '2', etc.

I can't wrap my head around how to play with DateDiff in order to have output like (considering we counting how many *days* each of the states last):

```
'1' | '2'
---------
  5 | 12
```

So I generally have two questions:

1. Is it even possible to do that with SQL?
2. If it is - how can that be done?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: forgot to mention DBMS is SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What is your DBMS?  SQL Server?

Comment: You need pivot to do this and get total day difference.

Comment: Can you explain the logic to get the result. I was unable to figure out ?

Comment: @Siyual MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Prdp I have an object that changes states. It has a bit more parameters, but the two I described in post are the only ones that have a timestamp and a property that describes the change between states. The goal is to get the amount of time the object spent in this or that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CASE` and get date difference as follows:

```
 SELECT
      (CASE WHEN Action = 'Action 1' THEN 
           SELECT ---- Date Diff GROUP BY Action 1
       ELSE 0 END) 1,
      (CASE WHEN Action = 'Action 2' THEN
          SELECT ---- Date Diff GROUP BY Action 2
       ELSE 0 END) 2
 END) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN Action = '1' THEN TOTAL_NO_OF_DAYS END ) AS '1',
       MAX( CASE WHEN Action = '2' THEN TOTAL_NO_OF_DAYS END ) AS '2'
  FROM
     ( 
        SELECT SUBSTR( Action, 17, 1 ) AS Action, 
               SUM( DATEDIFF( DAY, LEAD(Timestamp,1) OVER ( ORDER BY DAY ), DAY  
                             )
                   )
                 AS TOTAL_NO_OF_DAYS
      FROM Yourtable
    GROUP BY Action
  )
 WHERE Action IN ( '1' , '2' );
```